# Makng instance on "Heap"

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class, called `Ship()` and it looks like this

```
class Ship()
{
public:
    vector<Weapon*> Weapon
    void AddWeapon(Weapon*)
}

void MyShip::AddWeapon(Weapon*)
{
    Weapons.pushback(Weapon)
}
```

The `Weapon` class is an abstract base class, that must be derived from, for each type of weapon in the game. One of which is called `Lazer`

So in my code I can do:

```
int main()
{
    Ship MyShip;
    Lazer MyLazer;
    MyShip.AddWeapon(&MyLazer)
}
```

How do I make sure the object pointed to by the vector in `Weapons` does not go out of scope? I believe the answer is making the instance on the `heap` but I don't know.

Comment: Those aren't objects; they're function declarations. I'd start by fixing those first. And use `std::shared_ptr<>` if required. the last man out the door turns off the lights.

Comment: Sorry for the noobieness, but what?

Comment: To allocate the Lazer on heap, you need use Lazer * MyLazer= new Lazer(); MyShip.AddWeapon(MyLazer) ... And remember Delete it when you no longer need it.

Comment: `Ship MyShip();` means that `MyShip` is a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Ship`. Perhaps you meant `Ship MyShip;`?

Comment: Yes my bad I'll edit it thanks. So if I make it on the heap, it can't go out of scope?

Comment: Kieren, @WhozCraig is suggesting that you look up the `shared_ptr` class and use it wherever possible. It eliminates the `delete` book-keeping that @Tim3880 warns of by (simplified explanation) keeping a count of objects using the pointer. When there are no remaining users of the pointer, it is `delete`d for you. Handy.

Answer (score 2):

something like this is safest:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Weapon {

    virtual ~Weapon() = default;
};

struct Lazer : Weapon {

};

class Ship
{
public:
    void AddWeapon(std::unique_ptr<Weapon> weapon);

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Weapon>> _weapons;
};

void Ship::AddWeapon(std::unique_ptr<Weapon> weapon)
{
    _weapons.push_back(std::move(weapon));
}

// test

using namespace std;

int main(){
    auto ship = std::make_unique<Ship>();
    ship->AddWeapon(std::make_unique<Lazer>());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a few more questions sorry, First, I'm presuming that here _Weapon_ that was a struct could be a class instead. Is this true? Second, why call the vector __weapons_? Is the underscore a naming convention of vectors, or just to resolve a potential naming clash? Lastly what is _std::unique_ptr_? Is it the same as _shared_ptr_?

Comment: Yes, class and struct are the same thing except class is private by default and struct is public by default. The leading underscore is just the naming convention that I happen to use. Unique_ptr is a managed pointer that is not shareable. Have a read at cppreference.com

Answer (score 0):

You should create weapon instance from heap using "new", then you can decide when to delete the instance you create. You also should use parent class pointer to point you instance, that's called dynamic binding.

```
int main()
{
    Ship MyShip();
    Weapon * p = new MyLazer();
    MyShip.AddWeapon(p)
}
```

Comment: Yea this was what I thought would be possible thanks!